# Format the output of Color.ToString() to RGB values

Tags: c#, regex, converting

The method that I wrote below functions properly; however, I believe that the code I wrote is not clean nor "good".

I know the basics of regex but I do not know more advanced techniques as I am still an amateur at programming.

```cs
static string SimpleColorOutput(Color color)
{
    //If input = Color[A=255, R=8, G=14, B=21]

    string colorText = color.ToString();

    Match R = Regex.Match(colorText, @"R=(\d+)[,\]]");
    Match G = Regex.Match(colorText, @"G=(\d+)[,\]]");
    Match B = Regex.Match(colorText, @"B=(\d+)[,\]]");

    return $"R = {R.Groups[1].Value}, G = {G.Groups[1].Value}, B = {B.Groups[1].Value}";

    //The method returns "R = 7, G = 13, B = 20"
}
```

Also, is it better to just pass in the Color object

Comment: What do you need this for? Can you give us more information? What you're doing is pointless as you could just use the color components without turning it into a s string first and then parsing it o_O

Comment: How does `R=8, G=14, B=21` turn into `R = 7, G = 13, B = 20`? Shouldn't all values be 1 higher?

Comment: @Mast apparently _using regex doesn't cost a penny_ no longer applies; in fact it cost 3 pennies; ok, but at least the OP is consistent in his mistake ;-]

Answer (score 4):

The code in question is using the wrong tool (`Regex`) to achieve what you want. Using the string representation of a `Color` to get a string back is not a good way.

If one would pass a predefined color like `Color.Red` into that method it would fail by returning `R = , G = , B =` because the [`Color.ToString()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.tostring?view=netframework-4.8) returns

> A string that is the name of this Color, if the Color is created from
>   a predefined color by using either the FromName(String) method or the
>   FromKnownColor(KnownColor) method; otherwise, a string that consists
>   of the ARGB component names and their values.

If this is just for learning `Regex` you could change

```
string colorText = color.ToString();
```

to

```
string colorText = Color.FromArgb(color.R, color.G, color.B).ToString();
```

otherwise it would be better to just write

```
static string SimpleColorOutput(Color color)
{
    return $"R = {color.R}, G = {color.G}, B = {color.B}";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The method was indeed just for Regex practice not for Color. I would love to know the correct way to use Regex here.

Comment: @ShehabEllithy For your next question, make sure you share that information clearly in the question before answers arrive.